# How to get the value from the NsDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I am trying to get the value from the dictionary but its giving me null. Actually I have parsed the XML  and then convert it to the dictionary Following is the dictionary after conversion :(I got it in log)

```
dictionary: {
    "soap:Envelope" =     {
        "soap:Body" =         {
            GetServerStatusResponse =             {
                GetServerStatusResult =                 {
                    text = "<NewDataSet>\n  <Table1>\n    <ServerStatus>Standby</ServerStatus>\n  </Table1>\n</NewDataSet>";
                };
                xmlns = "http://tempuri.org/";
            };
        };
        "xmlns:soap" = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
        "xmlns:xsd" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        "xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    };
}
```

now I want to take the value from the **ServerStatus** tag. That is in this case , "StandBy".
But I am getting the null value in response. Please help? Is there a problem of spaces?

Comment: How you are trying to get the value from NSDictionary?

Comment: I am using XmlDictionary library and using its method for getting the value and saving it in the string , (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLString:(NSString *)string  . this is a method of this library

Comment: Let me post an answer for you.

Comment: Please share this  I really need that badly

Comment: Just posted an answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I guess your parser has not done really good job on your XML content... that is a kinda poor parsed result. have you tried different parser, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get to the `text` in `GetServerStatusResult` using the following code:

```
NSDictionary *soapEnvelope   = [dictionary valueForKey:@"soap:Envelope"];
NSDictionary *soapBody       = [soapEnvelope valueForKey:@"soap:Body"];
NSDictionary *statusResponse = [soapBody valueForKey:@"GetServerStatusResponse"];
NSDictionary *statusResult   = [statusResponse valueForKey:@"GetServerStatusResult"];

NSString *xmlString = [statusResult valueForKey:@"text"];
NSDictionary *textDictionary = [XMLDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:xmlString];
```

Now the xml in `text` key is converted to NSDictionary and you can easily get the value of `ServerStatus`

Comment: Thanks Adeel Ur Rehman it works but after digging two line more 
NSDictionary* tableDict = [textDictionary valueForKey:@"Table1"];
NSString*        resultStr = [tableDict valueForKey:@"ServerStatus"]

Answer (score 1):

There is no key `"ServerStatus"` in your dictionary.
The only key is `"soap:Envelope"`

and `"soap:Body"`, `"xmlns:soap"`, `"xmlns:xsd"` and `"xmlns:xsi"` are keys of the dictionary corresponding to the key `"soap:Envelope"`.

You can't access easily to `"ServerStatus"`, what you can do is acceding to `text` and then parse the value associated to retrieve `"ServerStatus"`

You should be able to get the value in `text` this way :

```
[[[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"soap:Envelope"] objectForKey:@"soap:Body"] objectForKey:@"GetServerStatusResponse"] objectForKey:@"GetServerStatusResult"] objectForKey:@"text"];
```

Comment: please share me the way to get the value of serverstatus

Comment: in this case "StandBy" , I want to get this as out put , so How to do that @KIDdAe

Comment: and what do you mean by that ? "You can't access easily to "ServerStatus", what you can do is acceding to text and then parse the value associated to retrieve "ServerStatus""  @KIDdAe

Comment: A dictionary is an object that associate a key and an object.
In your case there are dictionary associated to key in their parent dictionary.
For exemple `text` is a key and is associated to the string `"<NewDataSet>\n  <Table1>\n    <ServerStatus>Standby</ServerStatus>\n  </Table1>\n</NewDataSet>"` in the dictionary `GetServerStatusResult` (which is himself an object associated to a key in its parent).

See my edit

Comment: So How I shoudl do that I have no idea and I am not actually getting your point. Can you share the method instead of making me understand :) thanks in advance @KIDdAe